# Android Emulator is not playing sound

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, android-emulator

My Pixel 2 Android Emulator won't play sound, not from my app, not even from YouTube. I've restarted my computer, cold-booted the app, yet nothing works. I can use a physical device, but I'd like to have my emulator on the side while coding. Any Ideas?

Most of the other similar questions seem to be from 5-10 years ago, probably out of date? I've been working on this all day, so any advice is hugely appreciated.

Comment: may I know. which os ?

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan PC is Windows 10. Sorry for taking so long to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the problem, although it wasn't directly related with the Android Emulator. The problem was with my missing/outdated usb sound drivers. Here's basically how I fixed it.

1. Press on the Window Key
2. Type "Device Manager" and hit Enter
3. Open "Sound, video and game controllers"
4. Note the name of any of the driver with a yellow warning sign on it.
5. Head to Google, search for that driver name, and download it
6. Open the Android Emulator, Test, and Enjoy success :)

Comment: i have the same problem with my mac os. On mac OS there is no such thing as a missing driver with a missing sign on it 

Comment: This didn't help -- everything is clean with no yellow warning.

Comment: @Mike Then I'm not sure what could be going on with your device. But this worked for me.

Comment: @boc FWIW the lack of sound problem with my emulator was solved by deleting the offending device and re-creating it (in Android Studio Device Manager).

Comment: @Mike Great, glad you were able to get it solved

Answer (score 12):

Try restarting the virtual device from scratch without using a snapshot.  Here are two ways to do that:

1. Change the power button on the virtual device so that it actually does what it is supposed to do.
   Go to `Settings->System->Gestures->Press & hold power button`.  Select the `Power menu` option.  Then press and hold the power button on the virtual device and select `Restart`.
2. Start your virtual device with the `Cold Boot Now` option. [image]

Comment: cold boot worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me as well!

Comment: Cold boot helped me too… And I’m on Mac 

Answer (score 6):

I'm new to Android development and ran into the same problem. The initial volume of the emulator is incredibly quiet so when I increased it my issue was solved. Just press the top volume button underneath the power icon.

[image: volume icons]

Then use the slider to adjust the volume.

[image: volume slider]

(Putting this here in-case anybody else has a similar problem.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the already mentioned solutions worked.

What worked for me, though, was installing a different system image.

Putting this here in case someone else stumbles across the same problem.